# Concurrent Access to session warnings in Event Viewer when creating a page using XPM

Tags: cme, experience-manager, 2011-sp1, tridionui2012

I keep getting this huge list of warnings when creating a page using XPM. The errors all read:

> Concurrent access to Session object detected. Thread (xx) and (yy)
>   trying to access same Session concurrently. Session objects are not thread-safe! Component: Tridion.ContentManager Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Things are working properly, but I would like to solve this warning as well.

PS: Actually Tridion UI 2012

Comment: Sorry, no time to expand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212794/what-programming-practices-cause-tridion-to-report-that-a-session-is-used-on-ano

Comment: I thought I had properly searched through StackExchange before posting... I guess the only "new" parameter is that I only see it happen through a page creation in XPM...

Answer (score 1):

Since they are warnings, you should just ignore them. Probabaly better when you set logging on production to error only, then you won't see them.

If you want the explanation as to where they come from, see the answer below, duplicated from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212794/what-programming-practices-cause-tridion-to-report-that-a-session-is-used-on-ano/10489163/#10489163

> The problem does not only come about when storing a session, but also when storing any TOM.NET object (`Component`, `Page`, etc). Each such object has an internal reference to the Session that it was created from any access to the object may have to go back to the Session to retrieve the requested information from Tridion.
>
> Although most properties that are 'native' to the item type seem to be retrieved and kept on an instance, a call like `LoadApplicationData` may (have to) reach back to the Session to access the requested data. And if this call then happens on a different thread, you'll get the warning message you mention.
>
> I've started to look at every TOM.NET object I keep with suspicion and pre-load a lot of data I may need later when I first load the object from its Session.

Comment: Note that all Business Rule violations are logged as Warning. So I don't agree with the recommendation to set the log level to Error for Production; that will make problem analysis a lot harder.  I also don't agree with the statement that Warnings can simply be ignored; this particular Warning is indicating that a serious programming error is detected - concurrent access to a TOM.NET Session can lead to the weirdest issues (you are quite lucky if you get a lot of these Warnings but you don't notice anything else)